# exchange2013 IMAP SEARCH can support any other charset?

Tags: character-encoding, exchange-server, imap

I executed the command to exchange2013 imap service :

**A2 SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 SUBJECT "something"**

server response :

**NO [BADCHARSET (US-ASCII)] The specified charset is not supported.**

Exhange IMAP SEARCH can support any other charset?

how can I configure exchange to support UTF-8 or GBK?

thanks

Comment: The response tells you which charsets are supported, and the list consists of only US-ASCII.

Comment: :(,How can I search chinese from exchange IMAP server?

Comment: I don't know any way. Rumour has it that the next version of exchange will let you do it... but surely it has to be possible in some way today too, perhaps with some serverside configuration.